# Read timed out. (read timeout=None) when inserting records through simple_salesforce API in Python

Tags: python, timeout, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I am getting a "ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=' , port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=None)" while inserting records using bulk api of simple_salesforce library of python.
I have not set any timeout limit and I am trying to insert around 3M records.  I also tried inserting in small chunks, but it has the same issue.
Please let me know if any one of you have faced any such issues.

My Code:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce, SalesforceLogin

sf = Salesforce(username=    ''    
                ,password=  ''                        
                ,security_token= '')


bulk_data = []
for row in <data_to_be_inserted>.itertuples():
  d = row._asdict()
  del d['Index']
  bulk_data.append(d)

sf.bulk.<Custom_Object_Name>.insert(bulk_data)
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: In the target org do you see an entry in this user's login history? And your job's definition in Setup -> Bulk jobs? See if you can use simple-salesforce to query anything before writing. Maybe your company uses proxies and your traffic is swallowed

Comment: Yes, i do see an entry in the login history and also I am able to insert smaller chunks of data around 500k records. But this issue is more prevalent with larger amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try increasing the timeout on the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) session.

The simple_salesforce package uses [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) under the hood. Unfortunately, simple_salesforce does not appear to expose the `timeout` parameter.

Thankfully, it does allow you to customize the session and pass that into the `Salesforce()` constructor.

Here are two ways I found online to hack the session:

- [Define a custom HTTP adapter](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/148)
- This one seems easier: [Use `functools.partial`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/pull/303)

And a third and fourth:

- The Salesforce object has a "restful" method that can make arbitrary API calls. In other words, you can roll your own using, for instance, the [Bulk API 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/creating_bulk_requests.htm)
- Once you are this far in, however, perhaps you want to make the API calls directly using the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) library? It is a great library to work with, and you don't run into simple_salesforce's limitations.

I would love to be wrong about `timeout`. If anyone knows a way to set it from simple_salesforce, I am all ears.